# Enable Adobe Reader in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt5, adobe-reader

I would like to know how to enable Adobe Reader in QWebEngineView with PyQt5.
I've already created this piece of code without any success :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
web.settings().setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
web.load(QtCore.QUrl('file:///path/to/my/file.pdf'))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance!